# Can there be a set with a negative amount of elements. Such that: $|S|\lt0$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My professor jokingly, I assumed, expressed:

> [...] if we start thinking about sets with negative size reality starts crumbling before our eyes.

But I've been through this ordeal before, where limiting our view to real-world application and tangibility blocked progress in particular fields of maths *[Think geometry]*.

I would assume there are indeed ways for sets to be negative in cardinality. Looking around, I couldn't find any example or application of such a set.

**Is there a way to define a set $S$, such that $|S|\lt0$; If so is there any application to such a set?**

Comment: As I understand, we say that a set $S$ has finite cardinality $n$ if the members of $S$ can be mapped into a bijection with the set $\{ 1, 2, \ldots, n \}$. It is hard for me to visualize a set $S$ with negative cardinality like $-n$.

Comment: Cardinality can be viewed as a measure.  There are certainly such things as [Signed Measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_measure).  Take as an example a signed measure $\mu$ over the set of finite subsets of $\Bbb Z\setminus \{0\}$ given by $\mu(A) = |A\cap \Bbb N| - |A\cap (-\Bbb N)|$.  For examples, $\mu(\{1,2,3\})=3$, $\mu(\{-1,2,3\}) = 1$ and $\mu(\{-2,-1,1\})=-1$ and so on.  Whether this deserves to be called "cardinality" or not is questionable.  It will not have many of the same properties as what we traditionally call cardinality and will be less useful as a result.

Comment: As for cardinality as it is traditionally defined, we have the property that if $A\subseteq B$ then $|A|\leq |B|$.  Note that $\emptyset$ is indeed a subset of every other set and this implies that since $\emptyset\subseteq S$ we have $|\emptyset|\leq |S|$ implying $0\leq |S|$ for every choice of set $S$.  I.e. there is no such thing as a set with negative cardinality (*again, using the traditional definitions*).  The only way to change that is by changing the definition of cardinality to something else.

Comment: And also [my answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/136388/7206) to a similar question (also linked in the comments of the duplicate).